# Об употреблении "ежели" вместо "если и только если"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, словосочетания

Разумно ли использовать слово "ежели" вместо словосочетания "если и только если"?

Дополнение (от 05.07.2014)

По моему мнению, английское предложение "Q if P." следует переводить на русский язык  предложением "Q, если P.", а английское предложение "Q iff P." следует переводить на  русский язык предложением "Q, ежели P.".

Английские предложения "Q if P." и "Q iff P." пишутся по-разному, но произносятся одинаково. Русские предложения "Q, если P." и "Q, ежели P." и пишутся по-разному, и произносятся по-разному.

В английском языке союз "iff" появился в начале второй половины 20 века с целью замещения союза "if and onlу if" ("если и только если").

Дополнение (от 06.07.2014)

В современных толковых словарях русского языка слово "ежели" отождествляется со словом "если", при этом авторы указанных словарей оговаривают "устарелость", "разговорность" или иную "ущербность" слова "ежели" по сравнению со словом "если".

Дополнение (от 07.07.2014)

Математические тексты содержат два бинарных "или" и два [бинарных] "если". Одно из упомянутых бинарных "или" можно озвучить словом "либо", а одно из упомянутых [бинарных] "если" можно озвучить словом "ежели".

Мировосприятие лица, в языке которого есть только одно бинарное "или" и только одно  "если", гораздо хуже, чем мировосприятие лица, который пользуется двумя бинарными "или" и двумя "если".

Дополнение (от 08.07.2014)

По моим наблюдениям, в языке большинства гуманитариев есть только одно бинарное "или" в значении "либо" (то есть "эксклюзивного или") и только одно "если" в значении "ежели" (то есть эквиваленции).

Comment: Предложение "Q iff P" не произносится одинакого, так как оно не произносится. Слово iff используется только в определённых специализациях, в основном в математике. В разговорном языке оно отсутствует. Письменое написание слова образовалось, чтобы сократить *написание* "if and onlу if". Читая предложение "Q iff P", человек всё равно прочитает его в развёрнутом варианте, также как, увидев буквы etc., он не прочитает "этк", а прочитает "et cetera".

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы Вы не произносили предложение "Q iff P." из-за того, что "оно не произносится".

Comment: Предлагается новая формула: "единственно если" вместо "если и только если". ПОЯСНЕНИЕ. В английском "if and onlу if" onlу - это "единственно", а вот русская частица/наречие/союз ТОЛЬКО многозначная, и нужная "единственность" просто теряется среди других значений. Для справок: ТОЛЬКО 1) лишь (ограничение),  2) единственно/исключительно, 3) усиление, подчеркивание 4) уступка и др.

Comment: Я не предлагаю замещать словосочетание "если и только если" ни словом "ессли", ни словом "еслли", ни прочими русскоязычными аналогами "iff".

Comment: Слово "iff" сделано искусственно. Это, по сути, не настоящее слово - что-то в роде стенографии. Хотя его можно найти в некоторых словарях, оно обозначается как сокращённое от "if and onlу if". Оно сродни аббревиатурам, или даже амперсанду (&), который образовался от быстрого написания et (и - лат.).

Comment: Я считаю Ваш вопрос про русское слово ЕЖЕЛИ вопросом достойным дискуссии, но не надо его основывать на "слове" iff. Во первых, потому что это само по себе не независимое и не натуральное слово, которого *и в правильном английском-то* нету, а в русском и подавно быть не должно, а во вторых, потому что английский не должен таким образом влиять на наш язык. Он здесь ни при чём (разве что для примера), и не надо его использовать как костыль.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что слово "ежели" является устаревшим, поэтому в речи употребляется ситуативно. Смотрите на контекст. Если у Вас, скажем, диалог двух людей, то смотрите, может ли говорящий употребить устаревший оборот (в силу старомодности речи или в шутку). В словах автора можно употребить, если Вы нарочно хотите имитировать старую речь.
И, конечно, в официальной речи это слово будет смотреться странно.

Comment: А нельзя ли оживить почти вымершее слово "ежели", используя это слово при озвучивании логической связки, именуемой "эквиваленцией"?

Сравните два предложения:

1) "Три больше, чем два, если и только если два меньше, чем три.",

2) "Три больше, чем два, ежели два меньше, чем три.".

Answer (score 0):

Абсолютно неразумно использовать чисто разговорное (а может, и просторечное) слово в терминологии.

Comment: Я не способен оценить Ваше заявление про "абсолютную неразумность", потому что не наделён абсолютным разумом.

Comment: Схоластикой увлекаетесь? Что ж, богоугодное дело ))))))))

Comment: @Галактион,пожалуйста,будьте более дружески расположенным к товарищам по дискуссиям. По отношению к @Niemand Вы были немного высокомерным.Ну, признайтесь (хотя бы внутри себя, сам с собою! Никто ведь  Вас не хочет прилюдно поставить на колени. А наедине с собою Вы можете это сделать). Даже если @Niemand показался Вам слишком категоричным со своим абсолютом (поверьте, это у него слово-паразит), не стоит быть крапивой.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем Вам "если и только если"? В обычной речи это выражение не применяется, там вполне обходятся союзами "если только" и "только если".

"Если и только если" - это из области математики, например: A = B, если и только если A ⊂ B и B ⊂ A. Кстати, а здесь нельзя сказать просто, без патетики: A = B, если  A ⊂ B и B ⊂ A (объясните, пожалуйста, разницу между двумя выражениями).

А использовать союз "ежели" (устар. и разг.) в математике точно нельзя, у него жесткая стилистическая привязка. Так что пусть лучше математики говорят красиво "если и только если" - наверное, такая речь специально придумана, чтобы вызывать уважение у окружающих и отличать научный стиль от нейтрально-разговорного.

Comment: Что Вы называете "жёсткой стилистической привязкой" союза "ежели" (устар. и разг.)?

Comment: Невозможно, чтобы слово одновременно имело две стилевые характеристики: архаично-просторечную и научную.

Comment: Что Вы называете "стилевой характеристикой" слова?

Comment: То, что написано в толковом словаре. Если слово является нейтральным по стилю, то ничего не пишется. В противном случае указывается стиль речи для его использования  (разг., простор., книжн. и др.)

Comment: София, "если и только если" означает "необходимо и достаточно", а "если" означает "необходимо"

Comment: Предположим, что "стилевая характеристика" слова - это "то, что написано в толковом словаре". И что же написано в толковом словаре Ефремовой о слове "ежели"?

Comment: У Ефремовой - устар., по в других словарях: простор. и разг. Например: ОЖЕГОВ: ЕЖЕЛИ,  союз (устар.  и прост.). То  же, что  если. Грамота.ру: ЕЖЕЛИ, союз. Устар. и разг.=Если. А вот пример из современной литературы: "Я, ежели хотите знать, зубы пастой чистить начал, нашшот табаку и вина воздерживаюсь" (В. Астафьев). Здесь просторечный стиль.

Comment: Niemand, спасибо за информацию. А можете привести простенький пример?

Comment: "Ежели хотите знать", я прекращаю задавать Вам вопросы "нашшот" слова "ежели".

Comment: @София: "если и только если" - двухсторонние уравнение, как говорил мой учитель по математике. "А если Б" значит что А гарантировано при условии Б, но Б не гарантировано при условии А. "А если, и только если, Б" - одно гарантирует другое. Дорога мокрая, если шёл дождь. Но дорога мокрая может быть и по другой причине, поэтому "шёл дождь, если дорога мокрая" сказать нельзя. А теперь попробуем так: дорога мокрая, если и только если шёл дождь. Возможность того, что её мыли или что-то пролили и т.п. исключается. Если дорога мокрая, значит дождь шёл.

Answer (score 0):

Разве в математике вместо этого странного выражения не используется конструкция "**тогда и только тогда, когда**"? Или вы нашли такую конструкцию именно в математических статьях на русском языке?

*UPD. Возвращаясь к вопросу — на данный момент носителями "ежили" воспринимается как более старый вариант "если", а значит (на этом этапе развития языка) такая замена не передаёт значения, которое вы вкладываете, то есть неразумна (в том смысле, что не ведёт к пониманию). Есть свидетельства об использовании этого слова в значении логической эквивалентности?*

Comment: Что Вы назвали "этим странным выражением"?

Comment: "Если и только если". Я знаю "if and only if" в английском, но вот в русском слышу впервые. Не занимался серьёзной современной математикой  в математическом ВУЗе — возможно, действительно обиходное выражение. В той литературе, с которой имел дело в школе и университете, вместо него всегда использовалось "тогда и только тогда, когда" (я иногда сокращал как ТТТК, но сомневаюсь, что это частое сокращение)

Comment: 1. Итак, Вы "знаете "if and only if" в английском", но называете "этим странным выражением" словосочетание "если и только если".

2. Также я догадался, что "тогда и только тогда, когда" не кажется Вам "этим странным выражением" (например, из-за того, что "тогда и только тогда, когда" длиннее, чем "если и только если").

3. Надеюсь, что "тогда и только тогда, куда" тоже не покажется Вам "этим странным выражением".

Comment: Конечно. Речь идёт об осмысленности вопроса. В (математическом?) русском словосочетание "если и только если" крайне редко используется, а значит пока нет и необходимости его заменять. Можно, в принципе, заменить очень популярную формулировку ТТТК, если у учёных есть потребность.

Кстати, "тогда и только тогда, куда" я тоже не встречал в литературе.

Comment: Зато Ваша аббревиатура "ТТТК" годится как для "тогда и только тогда, когда", так и для "тогда и только тогда, куда".

Comment: моя аббревиатура нестандартная. Я её использовал при записи доказательств, чтобы не писать полное выражение. Любая аббревиатура может расшифровываться разными способами. У меня есть сомнения, что ТТТК хоть в каких-то кругах является устоявшимся сокращением, которое знают, как толковать.